# How To Run A Define From Imported Module To My Main File

Tags: python-3.x

I Want To Trigger Define in Main.py from my imported module(mymodule.py)
My Main.py

```
import mymodule
name=input('Your name')
def trigger():
      print(name)
```

My mymodule.py

```
from time import sleep

def mycodehere():
     sleep(555) #(i am just using sleep for u to understand what i am expecting , i have another code which                   is waiting For to complete)
     trigger()
mycodehere()
```

so please tell me what changes to make my code to get what i am expecting please Help Me please

I didn't know that much about python , but want to try something so please Help me

Comment: You mean you want to *import* a function defined in Main.py?

Comment: `from main import trigger`

Comment: Thanks For Reply ,I Updated My Requirement So Please Check My Code Again pls , help me please